# Frictionless pendulum using Rope resource from AS3 Fisix engine

Tags: actionscript-3, physics, physics-engine, physical-design

I'm developping a gameplay concept using AS3 Fisix engine in which I need for a pendulum to be frictionless. The idea is to define the head and tail positions (using the Fisix's Rope resource) by mouse clicking and dragging in the screen and let the pendulum swing so that it goes forth and gets back to its starting position without losing momentum, and keep doing this repeatedly.

So far, I managed to make the pendulum swing normally but still being affected by friction and gravity (it keeps moving until got totally still, like a real-life pendulum would do). After many trial-and-error experimentations, I realized that I couldn't find any obvious parameter to work with, either in FisixEngine instance or in the Rope object itself, which allows me to remove or disable the friction from the simulation so that the frictionless behavior could be achieved.

Sorry if I'm not being specific enough, but I would appreciate if you guys could shed some light in this issue. Is there any formula that can be applied to any of the existing Fisix objects parameters (gravity, velocity, thrusts etc) that can be combined to achieve the described? I mean, how would you solve this considering only that the Rope resource is required?

Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking through the [fisix documentation](http://www.fisixengine.com/api/com/fileitup/fisixengine/resources/Rope.html#methodSummary) for the `Rope` class I notice it has a `setFriction()` function and `setDrag()` inherited from a parent class. I would assume setting those to `0` would result in a no loss pendulum.

Comment: +1 for checking the most obvious place in the universe, the documentation.:)

Comment: Thx a lot for the reply. Sorry for not mentioning first that I've tried a couple of parameters changes, including drag and friction, which are set to zero by default, and unfortunatelly it is the situation I started to deal with. Although I haven't tried with the rope object, I verified that friction is bound to the interaction between surfaces, and it's not necessarily a pendulum-'air' interaction (I presume that the effect of removing friction internally to the engine, physically speaking, is achieved by manipulating forces and vectors and other things). Thx a lot for the research, anyway:)